# android xml textview take space after a imageview

Tags: java, android, xml

i have used a imageview and textview and i want my text to fill the gap after my image

im attaching a sshot of what im expecting below
[text is not filling gap below imageview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcwsR.png)

```
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/AppCompatImageView2"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:src="@drawable/play_store_512" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/AppCompatTextView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                    android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                <androidx.legacy.widget.Space
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="8dp" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/AppCompatTextView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

A solution to fix this gap below imageview

Comment: Do you want your second textView to be completely below your imageView? Because that is possible with RelativeLayout. But if you want your textView to start on right of imageView and then take the space below imageView also, I don't think its possible.